# Always display tabBarController when pushed to any viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I have 1 UITabbarController with 3 ViewControllers belong to its named aVC-bVC-cVC(VC = ViewController). Then I have 1 MenuSideBar have others 3 ViewControllers named dVC-eVC-fVC.

All I want is whenever I push to dVC or eVC or fVC my UITabbarController always display. How I can do that ? I really stuck at this point. I have to try many ways even custom a tabbarController myself but still not working.

Please help me. I really need help on this case.

Very thank you.

Comment: You can only do that by adding a UITabBar itself on `dVC-eVC-fVC`. And on click of the tabs event always changed the root view controller to nil and make again as UITabBarController as rootview controller and opened the selected index passed as a notification

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Hi, you mean is I need create UITabbar for each View I want to display a same Tabbar like UITabbarController ?

Comment: Exactly. Only way to achieve that

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari hi, do you have any example or tut about this case ? I still don't know what I should do exactly. Pls help me in this case, I stuck at here for 3 days with my work hard but still can't do what I need.

Comment: Ok, I ll post a my sample which I will make and upload on github and will explain in answer shortly

Comment: I have posted my answer with a demo sample github link made my me and a explanation too.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Very thank you, I will check out later.

Comment: Ok, Check and let me know and if it works, please accept as a tick. Thanks

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Yes, its working exactly what I want but I didn't use NSNotifications before so I need time to learn about NSNotifications first before I deep into your project and understand it clearly. Thank you very much.

Comment: If it helps, can you accept this as a tick. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made the sample demo for you in **Objective C** using **SWRevealViewController** as you had tagged that in your question. I have used the **XCode 7.1.1** version. Make sure to open this demo in **7.x** versions of XCode. This problem can also be solved by other side menu libraries like **MFSideMenu** etc

Here is the link of the demo sample made by me according to your requirements.
https://github.com/RajanMaheshwari/TabBarControllerApp

**EXPLANATION:**

In order to keep a tab bar always in your app you have to add a TabBar on every controller which is not a added viewController of `UITabBarController`. In my sample demo I have taken the various Controllers

**1.**`LeftSideViewController` - which will be the left side panel for whole app.

**2.**`MainTabBarViewController` - which will be the `UITabBarController` subclass and it will be connected to two other view controllers which will be the part of `MainTabBarViewController`.
----**a.**`TabFirstViewController`
----**b.**`TabSecondViewController`

**3.**`FirstViewController`- which will be the one that will from **LeftSideViewController's** table view and has its own `UITabBar` added.

**4.**`SecondViewController`- which will be the one that will from **LeftSideViewController's** table view and has its own `UITabBar` added.

Import the **SWRevealViewController** folder.
In your AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method we need to make the root view controller as the **MainTabBarViewController**.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder<UIApplicationDelegate,SWRevealViewControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SWRevealViewController *viewController;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "LeftSideViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "MainTabBarViewController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

   //Here Adding some notification observers which will be fired whenvever a tabbar index in clicked of the viewcontrollers whose parent is not UITabBarController class and the left side menu ones too.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(backToTabIndexControllerFirst) name:@"backToTabIndexControllerFirst" object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(backToTabIndexControllerSecond) name:@"backToTabIndexControllerSecond" object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(firstVCWithoutNAV) name:@"firstVCWithoutNAV" object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(secondVCWithoutNAV) name:@"secondVCWithoutNAV" object:nil];

    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window = window;
        UIStoryboard* storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        LeftSideViewController *leftSideController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftSideViewController"];
        MainTabBarViewController *mainTabBarController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTabBarViewController"];
        SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController =  [[SWRevealViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithRearViewController:leftSideController frontViewController:mainTabBarController];

    mainRevealController.delegate = self;
    self.viewController = mainRevealController;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Methods Definations of all observers added

**AppDelegate.m**

```
-(void)firstVCWithoutNAV{

    self.window.rootViewController = nil;
    UIStoryboard * storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController * firstVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstNAV"];
    LeftSideViewController *leftSideController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftSideViewController"];
    SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithRearViewController:leftSideController frontViewController:firstVC];

    mainRevealController.delegate = self;

    self.viewController = mainRevealController;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
}

-(void)secondVCWithoutNAV{

    self.window.rootViewController = nil;
    UIStoryboard * storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController * secondVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondNAV"];
    LeftSideViewController *leftSideController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftSideViewController"];
    SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithRearViewController:leftSideController frontViewController:secondVC];

    mainRevealController.delegate = self;

    self.viewController = mainRevealController;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

}

-(void)backToTabIndexControllerFirst{
    UIStoryboard* storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    LeftSideViewController *leftSideController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftSideViewController"];


    MainTabBarViewController *mainTabBarController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTabBarViewController"];

    SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithRearViewController:leftSideController frontViewController:mainTabBarController];

    mainRevealController.delegate = self;

    self.viewController = mainRevealController;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
}

-(void)backToTabIndexControllerSecond{

    UIStoryboard* storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    LeftSideViewController *leftSideController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftSideViewController"];


    MainTabBarViewController *mainTabBarController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTabBarViewController"];

    //To make selected index as the one which is clicked from tab bar
    mainTabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
    SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithRearViewController:leftSideController frontViewController:mainTabBarController];

    mainRevealController.delegate = self;

    self.viewController = mainRevealController;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
}
```

In the Controllers which have no **UITabBarController** parent class, we will add a tabBar and set tabBar's delegate to **self** and add the tabBar's didSelectItem delegate method.

**FirstViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<UITabBarDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar;

@end
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SWRevealViewController *revealController = [self revealViewController];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:revealController.panGestureRecognizer];


    UIBarButtonItem* revealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal-icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:revealController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = revealButtonItem;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
    NSUInteger indexOfTab = [[tabBar items] indexOfObject:item];
    NSLog(@"Tab index = %u", (int)indexOfTab);

    if(indexOfTab == 0){
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"backToTabIndexControllerFirst" object:nil];
    }else{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"backToTabIndexControllerSecond" object:nil];
    }
}
```

The notifications fired from here will change the root controller of the application.

Similarly we will code for **SecondViewController**
Assuming that there is a Table For selection of various other controllers from LeftSidePanel, we will add the tableView's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method as follows:

**LeftSideViewController.m**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    SWRevealViewController *revealController = self.revealViewController;
    [revealController revealToggleAnimated:YES];

    // Used this just to show the animation completion and then changing the root
    [self performSelector:@selector(changeControllers:) withObject:indexPath afterDelay:0.3];

}

-(void)changeControllers:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{

    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"firstVCWithoutNAV" object:nil];
    }else{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"secondVCWithoutNAV" object:nil];
    }
}
```

We can also use other libraries as I already stated for side panel. Example
https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu

Hope this solves the problem!